# Why do we use private keywords in Java - in the context of Hibernate, or Forms (Spring)...?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am reading the Spring Documentation here (https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) and similarly Hibernate documentation... Little confused looking at the example (in the link) for class `Greeting`

```
public class Greeting {

  private long id;
  private String content;
```

So in both of these (Hibernate and Spring), the "thing" that is accessing my class is library magic. Yet, we seem to write `private` for these members - when we clearly know this will get accessed by "someone else" (the library form binding code). I have read through the definition of `public`, `private`, `protected` etc., I understand why the feature exists in the programming language - but just coming from Python/Django world, it seems like in Java the "best practice" is to write `private` in front of everything and then write a bunch of `getter/setter` code, even when it is perfectly obvious that the member (`content` in this case) is actually public and worse yet, you don't actually do anything in the getter setter anyway.

I went looking for "why do we use private members in Java" and that didn't give me any good results. The best I can find on google results is some random link (#1 results) that says "always make everything private". Java docs (on Oracle) say nothing. There are a few university websites that seem to repeat the same "always make everything private" without any explanation as to *why*..

My question is the following -

> For most projects that are not handling super complex edge cases, what is the purpose of using this `private` pattern with a bunch of `getter/setter` methods? Who does it actually help?

I am not saying there is never a reason to use it. Surely there is an enterprise with some edge case where this applies. But usually things that go in "Getting Started" for anything are applicable to most people. I am trying to understand if I am missing something obvious..

I tried making it `public` and that removed a bunch of code from my code base. I didn't see any negative effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly make them public, there's nothing saying you can't, but when you do this you are breaking encapsulation, which is one of the fundamental principles of object-oriented programming.

By making the members private, it ensures that they can only be modified or accessed via the declared methods of the class.

In the case of hibernate, it uses reflection to hydrate the object.  All access from your perspective should be through the accessors.

Comment: Not arguing for/against that perspective e. But looking at the definition of encapsulation it is not clear *how* making it public breaks encapsulation (or making it private adheres to it). I am using the Wikipedia definition "encapsulation refers to the bundling of data with the mechanisms or methods that operate on the data". The next sentence has a reference which says "Encapsulation is not Information hiding" :)

Comment: @Vasu that's 100% correct, encapsulation has nothing to do with data hiding, if you read my answer closely, you'll see that it also doesn't mention data hiding.  You can look at it like this, encapsulation PROTECTS those data.  Make the variable private and create an accessor, the data aren't hidden, but they're available only through the defined accessor method.